# Tableau driver-resolver definition for JDBC Drivers in a custom connector

Tags: jdbc, tableau-api

I'm trying to figure out how to get Tableau to recognize my JDBC Driver when creating a custom JDBC connector using the [Tableau Connector SDK](https://tableau.github.io/connector-plugin-sdk/docs/) . Currently when Tableau loads my custom connector I can tell the driver is not found because there is a link that shows up in the Connector that says:

- "Download and install the drivers, and then connect."
- Tableau online does not have the drivers for the **SAS data** I want to connect to: so I cannot download the drivers to install from Tableau
- Luckily I already have the .jar files and have placed them at C:\Program Files\Tableau\Drivers on Windows
- In the [Connector API Reference](https://tableau.github.io/connector-plugin-sdk/docs/api-reference.html) **"driver-resolver" states that: "This is mainly used for ODBC connections but can be used for JDBC as well"** but I do not see specific instructions for working with JDBC drivers explicitly. Except for the [Postgres JDBC Example](https://github.com/tableau/connector-plugin-sdk/blob/master/samples/plugins/postgres_jdbc/connectionResolver.tdr) which DOES NOT use a driver-resolver. I also have not seen a JDBC example in the [Resolvers github samples](https://github.com/tableau/connector-plugin-sdk/tree/master/samples/components/resolvers)
- In the Tableau logs I can see that the .jar files containing my driver are recognized by searching for their names, they are shown in the logs.

**Logs Environment Section Excerpt:**

```
"environment","v":{...all my jar files listed here}
```

**Drivers not being recognized screenshot that says to download the drivers**

[image: drivers not recognized screenshot]

**Finally, here is what my .tdr file looks like with my current driver-resolver definition that does not work**

```xml
<tdr class='sas_jdbc'>
    <connection-resolver>
        <connection-builder>
            <script file="connectionBuilder.js" />
        </connection-builder>

        <connection-properties>
            <script file="connectionProperties.js" />
        </connection-properties>
    </connection-resolver>

    <driver-resolver>
        <driver-match>
          <driver-name type='exact'>com.sas.rio.MVADriver</driver-name>
        </driver-match>
    </driver-resolver>
</tdr>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this for me? I feel like I'm close. An example using a JDBC driver-resolver in a .tdr file would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is that **driver-resolver** is not used in JDBC custom connector definitions. The problem I'm experiencing with getting the SAS JDBC Driver to work is because the SAS JDBC Driver is JDBC Type 2.0. JDBC Drivers need to be Type 4.0 to work with a Tableau custom connector using the Tableau Connector SDK.

The resolution is to use a Type 4.0 JDBC Driver which I have not seen from SAS yet.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a .tdr file with JDBC, as all the driver resolution happens in the connectionBuilder.js file today.  The URL of the connection there includes the driver name.  I added a story to our backlog to make this more clear.  I should also mention, that hopefully you are using 2019.4 or higher for the best experience. Thanks for using the SDK!

Comment: Hi - Thanks for reaching out. I see what you mean about the importance of connectionBuilder.js and the connection string but the URL does not include the driver name. The JDBC URL includes the "subprotocol":

jdbc:sasiom://company.address:port

"sasiom" is the "subprotocol" and the "driver class name" is com.sas.rio.MVADriver. overall, I'm uncertain if Tableau is recognizing the correct driver class name. The driver class name is not called out in the logs

SAS docs:
https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=jdbcref&docsetTarget=p1a7nrsg36gaf8n1j33tfwf7nsj7.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: For the benefit of SO community awareness, we are working through the questions in our official SDK repository: https://github.com/tableau/connector-plugin-sdk/issues/452